# System Log: Bios may corrupt low RAM, working around it

Tags: memory, bios

I really hope someone can assist me with a good answer.

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 (not sure about kernel).

- Asus Motherboard
- 1TB Hard drive
- 16G Memory

The whole computer is brand new, only like two weeks old. I am having different times computer freezes, and have the error that came from the log viewer:

AMI BIOS detected: BIOS may corrupt low RAM, working around it.

Most people say that it can be that the RAM is faulty, and it should be replaced. Others say it is the Ubuntu Kernel. I am also getting answers that the BIOS have a bug somewhere.

I would like to know - what can it be? Can this error make the computer freeze?

This isn't good.... any help??

Comment: Did you try a newer Ubuntu live cd (newer kernel)? In the grub-menu is an option to check the ram. Do you tried that?

Comment: It probably the chipset does not support memory remapping. What brand and model Motherboard do you have?

Comment: Are you experiencing your computer freezing up?  I have a system that is freezing up and I see this message.  That said, @colin-ian-king has convinced me that Linux is handling this properly and it's not the issue. (This is an old post but first in google results)

Answer (score 4):

This warning message basically means that some systems are known to have a BIOS that uses some parts of the low 64K memory region as a temporary storage, which means this memory should not be used by Linux at the same time (you get weird memory corruption bugs).  The kernel has detected that your machine is on the list of machines known to suffer from this problem and has marked this memory region so that it cannot be used by Linux.

This prevents any clashes between the BIOS and Linux.  So, you don't need to worry, the kernel has taken care to prevent any memory corruption issues for you automatically.

The error message comes from arch/x86/kernel/setup.c in the kernel.